# Non euclidean lines (finding endpoints of semicircle)

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

A non euclidean line in $\mathbb{RP}^1$ in terms of reflections about the unit circle can be written in the form

$A+B(\overline{w}+w)+C(\overline{w}w)=0$

Where $w=\frac{1}{\overline{z}}$

The equation I'm working with is $w+\overline{w}-2w\overline{w}=0$ and I am asked to verify that this is the equation of a semicircle with endpoints $O$ (the center of the unit cirlce) and 1 on the x axis. I was thinking that the coefficients would get me somewhere but I'm not too sure.

[image: picture of reflection]

Comment: not sure whatyou mean , what is a "non euclidean line " and are you woking in projective, euclidean , inversive or hyperbolic geometry. (I think best is to do it in eucledian - inversive geometry see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry

Answer (score 0):

If we write $w=x+iy$ with $x,y\in\mathbb R$ then $\bar w+w=2x$ and $\bar ww=x^2+y^2$. So you have the equation $A+2Bx+Cx^2+Cy^2=0$. In your specific case, $A=0,B=1,C=-2$ you have

\begin{align*}
2x - 2x^2 - 2y^2 &= 0 \\
x^2+y^2-x &= 0
\end{align*}

Completing the square you have

\begin{align*}
x^2-2x\tfrac12+\left(\tfrac12\right)^2+y^2&=\left(\tfrac12\right)^2 \\
\left(x-\tfrac12\right)^2+y^2&=\left(\tfrac12\right)^2
\end{align*}

which is the equation of a circle with center at $\left(\tfrac12,0\right)$ and radius $\tfrac12$. If you restrict it to the upper half plane, you get a semicircle of course.

Comment: w is already defined as $\frac{1}{\overline{z}}$ though

Comment: @John: I noticed, but since the equation as I read it refers to a circle passing through the origin, then prior to the inversion you must have had a circle passing through infinity, i.e. a line. Which is the vertical line $x=1$ you see in the illustration. Since you won't be able to verify that this passes through the origin, I assumed that the question must have been referring to the set of points $w$, not their preimages $z$.